# Exporting table data from PBI into pre-formatted Excel file

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

**Question:**

How would I create an Export button that moves a large amount of data from a table visual in a PowerBI Dashboard into a pre-formatted Excel file? Please consider the fact that the table will be filtered on by the users of the Dashboard.

Thank you for your help!

**Background context:**

In one of my PowerBI Dashboards, I included a page with a table and users can apply filters on it depending on the scope that they'd like to see. This works fine, but I wanted to give my users the option of exporting the data from the table visual into a pre-formatted Excel file.

I'm aware that PowerBI has a built in Export Data option for tables, but in addition to it not being very user-friendly, it doesn't give me the option of customizing the format of the exported Excel file.

Because of this, I attempted to build a Power Automate Flow to implement an Export button that fit my needs. A screenshot of the Flow can be found below:
[image]

It runs without any errors and technically works as intended. However, there are a few limitations that I was not aware of:

1. Since I'm working with a lot of data, users have to scroll down on the table visual in order to load in more rows. The "Add a row into a table" action seems to only interact with the rows that have already been loaded in. That means, unless the user scrolls all the way down on the table, which can take a very long time, the "Add a row into a table" action fails to take all rows into consideration.
2. The "Add a row into a table" action has a limit of adding 1,000 rows. I really don't know how to get around that.

Answer (score 0):

By the sound of your scenario, I would suggest you provide an Excel file pre-connected to the published PBI dataset, with the fields, slicers, formatting etc... in place. Your users will need "Build permission" on the dataset.

To get started, in Excel in the `Data` tab in the ribbon, on the left select `Get Data` > `From Power Platform` > `From Power BI`. Select your dataset, then build your pivot table as desired, with slicers, filters, formatting etc...

See [Connect Excel to Power BI semantic models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-connect-power-bi-datasets-excel) for more details.